# Too many dialog boxes to click through for TFS gated check-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkin

We have the gated check-in policy enabled in the project.

What always annoys me is the amount of user interaction which is required on every check-in, namely:

1. "You need to build your changes for validation..." dialog box pops up.
2. Build explorer window opens in IDE, I close it immediately.
3. After build completes, "Gated Check-In Committed" dialog box pops up.
4. A similar dialog box pops up again, now with the list of files to reconcile.

As I always choose the default action in each of the dialogs, I wonder if it is possible to automate somehow the whole procedure to make it transparent to me?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to TFS 2012 / VS 2012 the second popup doesn't appear to happen, you just get a notification in your pending changes window that lets you click to see the build.

It also allows you to do [batch gated checkins](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/06/13/batched-gated-builds-in-tfs.aspx) where X number of checkins are merged and go through 1 build.